# What is the most suitable format of the timestamp to be used in Firestore database?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I am trying to implement Firestore database timestamp in Swift IOS, I am trying to find which will be the most suited way to store the timestamp, so that the data could be fetched according to the timestamp accurately.

Below are the timestamps I am trying to use, but sometime the results retrieved according to the filter of timestamp is not accurate

```
FieldValue.serverTimeStamp()

Timestamp()

let timestamp = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
```

Code

```
let ref = Firestore.firestore().collection("messages").order(by: "timestamp", descending: true)

            ref.addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
                snapshot?.documentChanges.forEach({ (diff) in

                    let messageId = diff.document.documentID
                    let messageRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("messages")
                        .document(messageId)


                    messageRef.getDocument(completion: { (document, error) in
                        guard let dictionary = document?.data() as? [String : Any] else { return }

                        let message = Message(dictionary: dictionary)

                        print("we fetched this message \(message.text)")


                            self.messages.append(message)

                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.collectionView.reloadData()
                                let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.messages.count - 1, section: 0)
                                self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
                            }

                    })
                })
            }
```

Comment: Exactly what error are you facing and how you are converting again back to timestamp? Can you pls share some code or challenges you face in finding the actual difference.

Comment: @SohilR.Memon, actually the documents are not retrieved in order to the timestamp, that's the main issue they are retrieved randomly, even after using the "order" function

Comment: Can you pls post that code like how you are retrieving?

Comment: @SohilR.Memon added the code

Comment: Let me edit your code and post as an answer.

Comment: A timestamp format will depend on what you want to *do* with the timestamp i.e. 20191127, 827828789201 and a Timestamp property are all valid timestamps. This question is similar to [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59017647/not-able-retrieve-documents-in-chat-application-according-to-the-timestamp) and the code has the issues as previously discussed so you need to address that (e.g. reading all of documents and then re-reading them again one at a time, loosing ordering). You will need to fix those issues for any kind of timestamp ordering to work.

Comment: If you are asking how to *store* a timestamp in Firestore, it's covered [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp) and if you want to use your app to generate it, it's covered [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#data_types)